# datatable load data success but can't access it by name

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I wanna load datatable by ajax like this [link](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)

my ajax datasource is something like this

```
$result = DB::table('test')->get();
$test = [];
$i=0;
foreach ($result as $row):
    $test[$i]['id'] = "-";
    $test[$i]['kode'] = $row->kode;
    $test[$i]['date'] = $row->date;
    $test[$i]['name'] = $row->name;
    $test[$i]['total'] = $row->total;
    $test[$i]['payment'] = $row->payment;

    $i++;
endforeach;
return json_encode(['aaData' => $test]);
```

but i can't access data in my initializing datatable

```
var dTable = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "{{ URL::route('list.laporan.pembelian') }}",
    "columnDefs": [ 
        { "targets": 0, "className": 'details-control', "orderable": false, "data": null, "defaultContent": '' },
        { "data": "kode", "name" : "kode" },
        { "data": "date", "name" : "date" },
        { "data": "name", "name" : "name" },
        { "data": "total", "name" : "total" },
        { "data": "payment", "name" : "payment" }
    ]
});
```

i tried to print if data succesfully loaded in `console.log` with this script

```
dTable.on( 'xhr', function ( e, settings, json ) {
    console.log( 'Ajax event occurred. Returned data: ', json );
});
```

and it's give result like this

```
object
  aaData:Array[2]
    [0]:object
       id: "-"
       kode: "Pl001"
       date: "01/01/2015"
       name: "test1"
       total: "$12"
       payment: "credit"
    [1]:object
       id: "-"
       kode: "Pl002"
       date: "01/02/2015"
       name: "test2"
       total: "$3"
       payment: "credit"
```

I think that means I already success load data..
but why i still can't access it?

---

**update @ivar**

[image]

my table structure
[image]

Comment: Can you add your table structure as well?

Comment: @ivar wait a minute..i will post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you return the data the correct way. Take a look at the [Server-side processing page](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) of the datatables website.

The data you should return should be:

- draw (The `draw` counter that this object is a response to - from the draw parameter sent as part of the data request.)
- recordsTotal (Total records, before filtering (i.e. the total number of records in the database))
- recordsFiltered (Total records, after filtering (i.e. the total number of records after filtering has been applied - not just the number of records being returned for this page of data).)
- data (An array of data source objects, one for each row)

I will add how I implemented it with Ajax:

Table:

```
<table id="dataTables-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="col1">col1name</th>
            <th id="col2">col2name</th>
            <th id="col2">col2name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#dataTables-table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "type": "POST",
        "url": "url/to/page"
    },
    "columns": [
        { "name": "col1", "data": "col1" },
        { "name": "col1", "data": "col1" },
        { "name": "col1", "data": "col1" }
    ]
});
```

Comment: `[draw you received from the request]` should not be literal. You get a `draw` parameter you can access by `$_POST['draw']`. That value should be in the draw.

Comment: hm can't get clear idea...i guess i should look at datatable website

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to add `"name": "kode", "data": "kode"` (for all columnds. And then give your table header (`th`) the ID `id="kode"`.

Comment: i already change it like this post (th id, column name & kode)...but still not hope..i guess i need a explanation why in datatable website used `return draw 1`

Comment: Draw is the serial number if the request. Every time you update your ajax request draw will increase by 1. So the first time the datatables will send draw with value 1 to your server, and you need to return 1 as draw, the second time draw will be 2, and you need to return 2, and so on. If you refresh your page it will start with 1 again.

Comment: `draw` is default parameter which always sent? or i must sent it manually?

Comment: It's default which is always sent.

Comment: i get it working now by set `'draw' => $_POST['draw']` but datatable function like `sorting column`, `pagination`, `limit dispay data` can't run....i already try to get `recordsTotal` & `recordsFIltered` but it's always `null`..so i handle manually `recordsTotal` from how many data in database..but i have no idea about `recordsFiltered`..can yougive me hint?